# my dialogue in android activity crashes, what i missing?

Tags: android, android-dialog

This is my OnClickListener where i overloading my method called

```
DialogueSuccessful();
```

which should Launch Dialouge.

```
if (Inserted == true) {
    DialogueSuccessful();
    txt_FromDate.setText("");
    txt_ToDate.setText("");
    txt_total_payment.setText("");
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Did not Insert Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Here is my method implementation, app crashes during method implementation

```
public void DialogueSuccessful() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder.setMessage("Successfull")
        .setTitle("Hotels Reservation")
        .setPositiveButton("Nice", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
            }
        });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    AlertDialog Dialogue = builder.create();
    Dialogue.show();
}
```

This is my Exception at logcat:

```
11 - 02 10: 00: 51.993 28999 - 28999 / com.example.prof_mohamedatef.listview E / AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method
for android: onClick
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java: 293)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java: 4432)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java: 18339)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java: 725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5283)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 511)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java: 288)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java: 4432) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java: 18339) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java: 725) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 92) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5283) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 1102) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 869) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme(or descendant) with this activity.
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java: 347)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java: 316)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java: 281)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java: 80)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java: 214)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java: 257)
at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java: 357)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java: 261)
at com.example.prof_mohamedatef.listview.Booking_hotels.DialogueSuccessful(Booking_hotels.java: 448)
at com.example.prof_mohamedatef.listview.Booking_hotels.Confirm_Reservation(Booking_hotels.java: 419)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 511) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java: 288) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java: 4432) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java: 18339) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java: 725) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 92) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5283) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 1102) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 869) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

That's all of code i using to launch my desired dialouge, should i add any thing ?

Do me a favor if u please, Your help will be appreciated
Thank You

Comment: Change method signature to `public void DialogueSuccessful(View view)` if using `android:onclick="DialogueSuccessful"` in xml

Comment: Also instead of using `getApplicationContext()` use current Activity Context to create AlertDialog

Comment: Thanks, switching to Activity Context is succesul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

switching from

```
getApplicationContext()
```

to Activity Context is succesul

```
public void DialogueSuccessful(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Successfull")
            .setTitle("Hotels Reservation")
            .setPositiveButton("Nice", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                }
            });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    AlertDialog Dialogue=builder.create();
    Dialogue.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml file  activity tag.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have use onClick attribute in your xml-layout file. Also you have not use suitable theme for your project. show your xml or app theme activity.

Answer (score 0):

modify you dialogueSuccessful method

replace this line

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

with

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder =new AlertDialog.Builder(
  new ContextThemeWrapper(getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.Theme_Dialog));
```